# How to roast pork shoulder?

Tags: oven, pork, roast

I used to cook pork shoulder in a slow cooker, however found that this didn't render any of the fat out of it. I prefer a leaner meat, so I figure roasting this in the oven and letting the fat drip out of it would be good. So I want to know how to properly roast a pork shoulder as well as any helpful tips.

Comment: There's an excellent recipe for roasting shoulder for pulled pork at http://homesicktexan.blogspot.com/2010/05/texas-pulled-pork-oven-recipe.html , if you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properly?

You throw it in a pit with hard wood coals for at least 8 hours. Of course we don't refer to that as roasting. :)

Oven roasting is easier. Turn the oven on to 250F or so. Put something flavorful on the roast. Stick in a probe thermometer and put it in the oven.

Remove when the thermometer reads 150F. Let it rest for a few minutes before carving.

For more color and fat rendering you can roast at 450F for 10 minutes before dropping the oven to 250F and putting in the thermometer.

Flavorings are varied of course. Apple works well.

Comment: When oven roasting, what are some good choices of equipment to use? I'm guessing a dutch oven is pretty typical but I do not own one.

Comment: @Zombies- Basic roasting like what I described above only requires a deep roasting pan to catch juices, a wire rack to hold the meat off the pan, and a probe thermometer. Some recipes use foil to keep in moisture. There are many ways to go about this including a dutch oven. You should pick a method and try it or ask a separate question specifically about your chosen method.

Answer (score 0):

I like to simmer it with spices, cabbage and potatoes.  (add the veg later or it will go soggy).  Skim the fat off the top fairly frequently.